# how to reuse the duplicated rule name text in css rule

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have one css file with following rules that looks really terrible. is there anyway I can clean it up like using `&::` but it does not work

```
.alert-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}
.alert-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 15s linear;
  z-index: 3;
}
.alert-exit {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}
.alert-exit-active {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 15s linear;
  z-index: 2;
}

/* maybe clean it up like */
.alert {
  &::-enter {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 3;
  }

&::-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 15s linear;
  z-index: 3;
}

&::-exit {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}
&::-exit-active {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 15s linear;
  z-index: 2;
}

}
```

Comment: It's not `&::`, it's just `&`. CSS doesn't use `&`, that's for SASS. Which won't matter because it'll be compiled to regular CSS and look similar to how you have it now.

Comment: CSS doesn't support nested structure. You can use LESS or SASS to achieve this goal.